# SCALA: Reading JSON file with the path provided

Tags: scala

I have scenario where I will be getting different JSON result from multiple API's, I need to read specific value from the response.

For instance my JSON response is as below, now I need a format from user to provider by which I can read the value of Lat, Don't want hard-coded approach for this, user can provided a node to read in some other json file or txt file:

```
{
  "name" : "Watership Down",
  "location" : {
    "lat" : 51.235685,
    "long" : -1.309197
  },
  "residents" : [ {
    "name" : "Fiver",
    "age" : 4,
    "role" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "Bigwig",
    "age" : 6,
    "role" : "Owsla"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key of json using scala JSON parser as below. Im defining a function to get the lat, which you can make generic as per your need, so that you just need to change the function.

```
  import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

  val json =
    """
      |{
      |  "name" : "Watership Down",
      |  "location" : {
      |    "lat" : 51.235685,
      |    "long" : -1.309197
      |  },
      |  "residents" : [ {
      |    "name" : "Fiver",
      |    "age" : 4,
      |    "role" : null
      |  }, {
      |    "name" : "Bigwig",
      |    "age" : 6,
      |    "role" : "Owsla"
      |  } ]
      |}
    """.stripMargin

  val jsonObject = JSON.parseFull(json).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]

  val latLambda : (Map[String, Any] => Option[Double] ) = _.get("location")
    .map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("lat").toString.toDouble)

  assert(latLambda(jsonObject) == Some(51.235685))
```

The expanded version of function,

```
  val latitudeLambda = new Function[Map[String, Any], Double]{
    override def apply(input: Map[String, Any]): Double = {
      input("location").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("lat").toString.toDouble
    }
  }
```

Make the function generic so that once you know what key you want from the JSON, just change the function and apply the JSON.

Hope it helps. But there are nicer APIs out there like [Play JSON lib](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Converting-to-a-JsValue). You simply can use,

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val jsonVal = Json.parse(json)
val lat = (jsonVal \ "location" \ "lat").get
```

Comment: I used play library, but it's not fulfilling the purpose as I said I am writing generalized program to get values from JSON, so I will not be aware of what JSON Path use is going to provide, I am looking for something where user providers a JSON path and I can extract value using that

Comment: can you give me a format what your incoming key look like??